# HTML5 Input Pattern for Telephone Number

Tags: regex, html

```
pattern="^[01|02|03|07|08]{1}[0-9]{8-10}$"
```

I need 9-12 characters starting with 01, 02, 03, 07 or 08. Why is my pattern not working?

Comment: Test it in REGEX generator. There are lots out there.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* `^` and `$`. I tried to simplify your pattern:

- Changed `[01|02…08]` to `0(1|2…8)` because you need to use parenthesis as chevybow explained,
- Changed `{8-10}` to `{7,10}` because you said you *“need 9-12 characters”*, and `-` doesn't work in the `{}`.

This snippet works for me:

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="0(1|2|3|7|8)[0-9]{7,10}" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: `0|12345678` submits for your snippet

Comment: @chevybow True, need parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
^(01|02|03|07|08){1}[0-9]{8,10}$
```

Your issue was using `[]` instead of `()` checking for the first numbers. You need parenthesis with the logical ors. The way you had it you were matching literally against just one character of either any number or `|`.

For example:

`012345678` would have matched, as would have `|12345678` with the pattern you were using

Answer (score 1):

I think you tried to use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `(01|02|03|07|08)` instead of using the digits in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[01|02|03|07|08]`

But even when you use the version with the alternation, that would match 2 digits and would in your regex be followed by `[0-9]{8-10}` which will be a total of matching 10 - 12 digits instead of the 9 - 12

You could put the prepending zero before the charcter  class and leave 12378 inside the character class. That would be 2 characters, leaving matching 7 -10 following digits.

You don't need the `^` and `$` because the regex is already anchored.

[`0[12378][0-9]{7,10}`](https://regex101.com/r/leQbdb/1)